# scales_fill_continuous doesn't work (ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data:

```
df_1 <- data.frame(
  x = replicate(
    n = 2, expr = rnorm(n = 3000, mean = 100, sd = 10)
  ), 
  y = sample(x = 1:3, size = 3000, replace = TRUE)
)
```

And the follow function:

```
library(tidyverse)

ggplot(data = df_1, mapping = aes(x = x.1, fill = x.1)) + 
  geom_histogram(color = 'black', bins = 100) + 
  scale_fill_continuous(low = 'blue', high = 'red') + 
  theme_dark()
```

`scale_fill_continuous` doesn't work. The graph is black and gray.

Tks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem, I think, is that there are `nrow(df_1)` values for fill, but only 100 are needed. This could be solved by pre-calculating the bin positions and counts and plotting with `geom_col`, but a neater solution is to use `stat`. `stat` is supposed to be for computed variables (e.g. `stat(count)` - see `?geom_histogram`) but we can give it the vector `1:nbin` and it works.

```r
df_1 <- data.frame(
  x = replicate(n = 2, expr = rnorm(n = 3000, mean = 100, sd = 10)), 
  y = sample(x = 1:3, size = 3000, replace = TRUE)
)

library(tidyverse)
nbins <- 100
ggplot(data = df_1, mapping = aes(x = x.1, fill = stat(1:nbins))) + 
  geom_histogram(bins = nbins) + 
  scale_fill_continuous(low = "red", high = "blue")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-01-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

The `aes` `fill` should be `stat(count)` rather than `x.1`

```r
ggplot(data = df_1, mapping = aes(x = x.1, fill = stat(count))) + 
  geom_histogram(color = 'black', bins = 100) + 
  scale_fill_continuous(type = "gradient", low = "blue", high = "red") +
  theme_dark()
```

[image]