# Fill Aesthetic not working in geom_histogram with numeric value

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to make a histogram shaded with a fill aesthetic.  I have to use a continuous variable for the fill aesthetic because I want to shade it using `scale_fill_gradent2()`.  But `ggplot2` just plots a gray histogram, with no fill yet throws no error.  Here is a MWE:

```
library(ggplot2)

dat <- rnorm(1000)

ggplot() + 
  geom_histogram(aes(x=dat, fill=dat))
```

Creates:

[image]

How do I fill the histogram with a continuous color?

I'm using ggplot2 3.2.0.

Comment: How would you like to fill the histogram? What you have doesn't work because there's 1000 values, whereas when you plot a histogram, the "dat" values are counted per bin

Comment: You can fill it according to the density or count : ggplot() + geom_histogram(aes(x=dat,fill=..density..))

Comment: I want to fill the histogram according to the value on the x-axis.

Comment: I think you'll find the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59811647/scales-fill-continuous-doesnt-work-ggplot2/59811845#59811845)

Comment: @AllanCameron that post has a solution that works, but I actually prefer the solution by StupidWolf, as it's much more parsimonious

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To fill it with the x values, you do:

```
dat <- rnorm(1000)
ggplot() + geom_histogram(aes(x=dat,fill=..x..)) + scale_fill_viridis_c()
```

[image]